# Using EasyBMP to extract pixel data per channel and flattening the pixel data - writing back extracted data results in different image

Tags: c++, arrays, image, flatten, bmp

Quite a newbie question but I am struggling with extracting the pixels from a `BMP` object, provided **EasyBMP** library, where each pixel is represented by the following structure:

```
typedef struct RGBApixel {
    ebmpBYTE Blue;
    ebmpBYTE Green;
    ebmpBYTE Red;
    ebmpBYTE Alpha;
} RGBApixel;
```

with

```
#define unsigned char ebmpBYTE
```

and where the pixels inside `BMP` are represented by pointer to an array of pointers:

```
 RGBApixel** Pixels;
```

so basically a two dimensional array (also accessing pixels is done by using `[i][j]` throughout the whole source code of the library).

I'd like to get 3 one dimensional arrays (flattened 2D arrays basically) out of `BMP` - one for each color channel (R, G and B) excluding the alpha:

```
BMP bmp_file;
bmp_file.ReadFromFile("test.bmp"); // 640x480 bitmap image

unsigned int dimensions = bmp_file.TellWidth() * bmp_file.TellHeight();
auto pixels_host_red_channel = new unsigned char[dimensions];
auto pixels_host_green_channel = new unsigned char[dimensions];
auto pixels_host_blue_channel = new unsigned char[dimensions];

for (unsigned int col = 0; col < bmp_file.TellWidth(); col++)
{
    for (unsigned int row = 0; row < bmp_file.TellHeight(); row++)
    {
        *(pixels_host_red_channel + col * bmp_file.TellHeight() + row) = bmp_file.GetPixel(col, row).Red;
        *(pixels_host_green_channel + col * bmp_file.TellHeight() + row) = bmp_file.GetPixel(col, row).Green;
        *(pixels_host_blue_channel + col * bmp_file.TellHeight() + row) = bmp_file.GetPixel(col, row).Blue;
        *(pixels_host_grayscale + col * bmp_file.TellHeight() + row) = 0;
    }
}
```

The reason is that I want to do some operations on a per channel basis using CUDA and (CUDA beginner here) so far the easiest way (without touching the library's source code) is doing what I've posted above.

Before going further I tried simply writing back the pixel data into the `BMP` object and writing it to a file:

```
unsigned char alpha = bmp_file.GetPixel(0, 0).Alpha; // My image has the same alpha across all pixels so for the image it works just fine

BMP bmp_original(bmp_file);
for (unsigned int col = 0; col < bmp_original.TellWidth(); col++)
{
    for (unsigned int row = 0; row < bmp_original.TellHeight(); row++)
    {
        unsigned char red = *(pixels_host_red_channel + col * bmp_original.TellHeight() + row);
        unsigned char green = *(pixels_host_green_channel + col * bmp_original.TellHeight() + row);
        unsigned char blue = *(pixels_host_blue_channel + col * bmp_original.TellHeight() + row);

        RGBApixel pixel_original { red, green, blue, alpha };
        bmp_original.SetPixel(col, row, pixel_original);
    }
}
```

The code above results in

[image: Copy]

with the original looking like this:

[image: Original]

Here is the full code (library excluded):

```
#include "EasyBMP.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Load BMP file into CPU memory
    BMP bmp_file;
    bmp_file.ReadFromFile("test.bmp");

    unsigned int dimensions = bmp_file.TellWidth() * bmp_file.TellHeight();
    unsigned int channel_size = sizeof(unsigned int) * dimensions;
    // EasyBMP does not offer direct access to the raw pixel data array
    // but instead maps all 4 channels (R, G, B and A) to a structure
    // Here we allocate CPU memory for each channel
    auto pixels_host_red_channel = new unsigned char[dimensions];
    auto pixels_host_green_channel = new unsigned char[dimensions];
    auto pixels_host_blue_channel = new unsigned char[dimensions];
    auto pixels_host_grayscale = new unsigned char[dimensions];

    // and copy the respective R, G or B value to the given array
    for (unsigned int col = 0; col < bmp_file.TellWidth(); col++)
    {
        for (unsigned int row = 0; row < bmp_file.TellHeight(); row++)
        {
            *(pixels_host_red_channel + col * bmp_file.TellHeight() + row) = bmp_file.GetPixel(col, row).Red;
            *(pixels_host_green_channel + col * bmp_file.TellHeight() + row) = bmp_file.GetPixel(col, row).Green;
            *(pixels_host_blue_channel + col * bmp_file.TellHeight() + row) = bmp_file.GetPixel(col, row).Blue;
            *(pixels_host_grayscale + col * bmp_file.TellHeight() + row) = 0;
        }
    }
    //printf("col:row = %d:%d\n\n", col, row);

    // Following line is not really useful except for displaying info
    // about the alpha channel (for the test image it is all equal, 
    // which is generally not the case). In case alpha channel needs
    // to be handled in some way, use the same steps as for the other
    // channels to ensure covering cases where alpha is not the same
    // across all pixels
    unsigned char alpha = bmp_file.GetPixel(0, 0).Alpha;

    BMP bmp_copy(bmp_original);
    for (unsigned int col = 0; col < bmp_copy.TellWidth(); col++)
    {
        for (unsigned int row = 0; row < bmp_copy.TellHeight(); row++)
        {
            unsigned char red = *(pixels_host_red_channel + col * bmp_copy.TellHeight() + row);
            unsigned char green = *(pixels_host_green_channel + col * bmp_copy.TellHeight() + row);
            unsigned char blue = *(pixels_host_blue_channel + col * bmp_copy.TellHeight() + row);

            RGBApixel pixel_original { red, green, blue, alpha };
            bmp_copy.SetPixel(col, row, pixel_original);
        }
    }
    // Write original file to a new file (for verification it's the same)
    bmp_copy.WriteToFile("test_copy.bmp");

    delete pixel_host_red_channel;
    delete pixel_host_green_channel;
    delete pixel_host_blue_channel;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. There were two issues:

- The order of iteration (row-major vs column-major):

  ```
  for (unsigned int row = 0; row < bmp_file.TellHeight(); row++)
  {
      for (unsigned int col = 0; col < bmp_file.TellWidth(); col++)
      {
          *(pixels_host_red_channel + row * bmp_file.TellWidth() + col) = bmp_file.GetPixel(col, row).Red;
          *(pixels_host_green_channel + row * bmp_file.TellWidth() + col) = bmp_file.GetPixel(col, row).Green;
          *(pixels_host_blue_channel + row * bmp_file.TellWidth() + col) = bmp_file.GetPixel(col, row).Blue;
          *(pixels_host_grayscale + row * bmp_file.TellWidth() + col) = 0;
      }
  }
  ```
- The way the values are stored inside `RGBApixel` - BGRA and not RGBA:

  ```
  for (unsigned int row = 0; row < bmp_file.TellHeight(); row++)
  {
      for (unsigned int col = 0; col < bmp_file.TellWidth(); col++)
      {
          unsigned char red = *(pixels_host_red_channel + row * bmp_file.TellWidth() + col);
          unsigned char green = *(pixels_host_green_channel + row * bmp_file.TellWidth() + col);
          unsigned char blue = *(pixels_host_blue_channel + row * bmp_file.TellWidth() + col);

          RGBApixel pixel_original {blue, green, red, alpha};
          bmp_original.SetPixel(col, row, pixel_original);
      }
  }
  ```

The second one just shows it's much better to initialize the structure and then fill  it with the values addressing each data field respectively instead of just using the short initialization `{ ... }`.